# groovy parse value from map to html select box

Tags: grails

I got a map like this

```
company = [no:[01, 02], name:[abc, def]]
```

How can I display those information into select box on html?, it means that each option has value:

```
option1: 01: abc
option2: 02: def
```

I tried

```
<select>
   <g:each in="${grailsApplication.config.Companies}" var="company">
      <option>${company}</option>
   </g:each>
</select>
```

but it only shows 
option1: no:[01, 02]
option2: name:[abc, def]]
Please help, thanks!

Note: ${grailsApplication.config.Companies} = array company at above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement it like this

```
<select>
   <g:each in="${grailsApplication.config.Companies[no]}" var="company" status="index">
     <option value="${grailsApplication.config.Companies['no'][index]}">${grailsApplication.config.Companies['name'][index]}</option>
   </g:each>
</select>
```